# Access VBA code to paste value (Max Date) from a vba export code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I currently have an Access query that exports a .csv file to a directory with headers. I need to take the date column and take the MAX date and add it to an excel spreadsheet through the VBA code. I will have 10-20 access database that does this. Below is the export VBA code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Sub ExportQuery()
Dim PathName As String, FileName As String
PathName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CsvFiles\"
FileName = Replace(Replace(CurrentProject.Name, "sharepoint_", ""), ".accdb", "")
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Qry_ExportToCsv", PathName & FileName & ".csv", HasFieldNames:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the question?

Comment: Do you want to export max date only?